# Spring Autowired object is null

Tags: spring, groovy, autowired

I have a problem with autowiring an object, it keeps getting null. I have a `BookManager` which I have defined in my beans. This `BookManager` I need to be autowired to all objects that extends my `AbstractBook`, but I keep getting null of the autowired object. I have googled alot and it seems that many people are making some mistakes regarding autowire but I can't find a solution for my setup. This is how it looks:

My beans:

```
beans = {
    bookManager BookManager
}
```

BookManager.groovy

```
class BookManager {

    void addText(text){
        println text
    }
}
```

AbstractBook.groovy

```
abstract class AbstractBook extends DefaultActor {

    @Autowired
    BookManager bookManager

    protected final void act(){
        loop{
            react{ message ->
                println message
            }
        }
    }

    abstract void method1()
}
```

Book1.groovy

```
@Component
class Book1 extends AbstractBook { 

    @Override
    void method1(){
        bookManager.addText("book 1 text")
    }
}
```

A solution that would work is to define book1 in my beans but I'm not able to do that because there will be alot of books generated. So I was hoping it would work with adding the annotation `@Component` for each book but it does not work.

Does anyone know how I can make bookManager available for all books?

Comment: how are you getting a reference to Book1?  Are you autowiring it in another class?  What happens if you annotate BookManager with @Component and get rid of it from the beans file?

Comment: well I just realized I'm doing new Book1() which is not the correct approach for a component. Is it possible to get the autowired object on object that I create with new?

Comment: If you're using `new Book1()` you could constructor inject your `bookManager` instance. If you want the Spring `Autowired` behavior to work for a `Book1` instance you'd need to start the spring container and let it wire up everything for you.

Comment: thanks @Durandal, do you have an example of how to use the spring container since I will need to inject the bookManager in many layers and don't like that very much? Would I need to define my Book1 manually in this spring container or is it possible to make it automatically somehow?

Comment: It would depend on how your app is currently configured. Basically you would want to create a test that loads your spring config, usually done with annotations these days. Normally I use class based Spring config so my annotation looks like this: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = [RootConfig])` Check out the spring docs here: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing